# CheckBox for all and for single does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I am trying to make an array of listing using checkbox function, the function checks if the all checkbox is clicked then put all listings in the array, if it is clicked to uncheck it pulls all array values, and if a single listing is checked it adds to the array , and if its unchecked when its single or all listing values its value from the array is taken out. Yet on the first run if all selected i cant remove a single value by selecting one checkbox, and after all are checked and unchecked i cant add a single value into array by checking a single option.

```
var lstsToEdit = [];

lstDisplay("act");

$(".tab-listings-selection").on("click", function() {
    var lstType;
    if(this.id == "mnLstAct") lstType = "act";
    if(this.id == "mnLstInact") lstType = "inact";
    if(this.id == "mnLstDraft") lstType = "draft";
    document.getElementById("mnLstAct").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    document.getElementById("mnLstInact").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    document.getElementById("mnLstDraft").style.fontWeight = "normal";
    this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    lstDisplay(lstType);
});

function lstDisplay(type){  
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";

var tblLsts = document.createElement("table");
tblLsts.setAttribute("id", "tblLsts");
$("#main").append(tblLsts);
var tblLstsHRow = tblLsts.insertRow(0);
var tblLstsHThumb = tblLstsHRow.insertCell(0);
var tblLstsHTitle = tblLstsHRow.insertCell(1);
var tblLstsHStock = tblLstsHRow.insertCell(2);
var tblLstsHPrice = tblLstsHRow.insertCell(3);
var tblLstsHExpiry = tblLstsHRow.insertCell(4);
var tblLstsHSection = tblLstsHRow.insertCell(5);
var tblLstsHAll = tblLstsHRow.insertCell(6);
tblLstsHThumb.outerHTML = "<th></th>";
tblLstsHTitle.outerHTML = "<th>Title</th>";
tblLstsHStock.outerHTML = "<th>In Stock</th>";
tblLstsHPrice.outerHTML = "<th>Price</th>";
tblLstsHExpiry.outerHTML = "<th>Expiry</th>";
tblLstsHSection.outerHTML = "<th>Section</th>";
tblLstsHAll.outerHTML = "<th>All<input id=\"lstsAllChk\" class=\"lstChk\" type=\"checkbox\"/></th>";   
var lstThumb = [];  
var listings;

if (type == "act") lsts = lstAct;
if (type == "inact") lsts = lstInact;
if (type == "draft") lsts = lstDraft;
for (var lstIndex = 1; lstIndex < lsts.results.length+1; lstIndex++){
    var lst = lsts.results[lstIndex-1];         
    var row = document.getElementById("tblLsts").insertRow(lstIndex);
    var colThumb = row.insertCell(0);
    var colTitle = row.insertCell(1);
    var colStock = row.insertCell(2);
    var colPrice = row.insertCell(3);
    var colExpiry = row.insertCell(4);
    var colSection = row.insertCell(5);
    var colSelect = row.insertCell(6);          
    var lstJ = JSON.parse($.ajax({url: "listings/" + lst.listing_id + ".json", async: false}).responseText);
    colThumb.innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + lstJ.results[0].url_75x75 +"\">";
    colTitle.innerHTML = lst.title;
    colStock.innerHTML = lst.quantity;
    colPrice.innerHTML = lst.price;
    colSelect.innerHTML = "<input id=\"" + lst.listing_id + "\" class=\"lstChk\" type=\"checkbox\"/>";

    for (var secIndex = 0; secIndex < sects.results.length; secIndex++){
        if (sects.results[secIndex].shop_section_id == lst.shop_section_id)
            colSection.innerHTML = sects.results[secIndex].title;
    }           
}

$.getScript("tableSort.js");    
}

$(".lstChk").on("click", function() {
    if(this.id == "lstsAllChk" && this.checked){
        for(var lstIndex = 0; lstIndex < document.querySelectorAll(".lstChk").length; lstIndex++){
            var lstId = document.querySelectorAll(".lstChk")[lstIndex].id;
            //if(lstsToEdit.findIndex( function(value){ value == lstId;}) == -1){;
                $("#"+lstId).prop("checked");
                lstsToEdit.push(lstId);
            //}
        }
    }
    else if(this.id == "lstsAllChk" && !this.checked){
        for(var lstIndex = 0; lstIndex < document.querySelectorAll(".lstChk").length; lstIndex++){
            var lstId = document.querySelectorAll(".lstChk")[lstIndex].id;
            $("#"+lstId).prop("checked", false);
            var index = lstsToEdit.findIndex( function(value){ value == lstId;});
            lstsToEdit.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    else if(this.checked) lstsToEdit.push(this.id);
    else {
        var index = lstsToEdit.findIndex( function(value){ value == this.id;});
        lstsToEdit.splice(index, 1);
    }

if(lstsToEdit.length > 0) document.getElementById("lstEdit").style.display = "block";
else document.getElementById("lstEdit").style.display = "none";
console.log(lstsToEdit);
});
```

table sort js

```
$("th").on("click", function() {
var table = this.closest("table");
var selection = $(this).text();
var col = this.cellIndex;
var tbl = [];
var order = [];

for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.rows.length; rowIndex++){
    if (rowIndex > 0){
        tbl.push([]);
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < table.rows[rowIndex].cells.length; colIndex++){
            tbl[rowIndex-1].push(table.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex].innerHTML);
            if (colIndex == col){
                order.push([]);
                order[rowIndex-1].push(tbl[rowIndex-1][colIndex]);
                order[rowIndex-1].push(rowIndex-1);
            }
        }
    }           
}

for (var rowIndex = table.rows.length-1; rowIndex > 0; rowIndex--){
    table.deleteRow(rowIndex);
}

var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9]/g
order.sort (function (a,b){
    var aA = a[0].replace(reA, "").toLowerCase();
    var bA = b[0].replace(reA, "").toLowerCase();
    if(aA == bA) {
        var aN = parseInt(a[0].replace(reN, ""), 10);
        var bN = parseInt(b[0].replace(reN, ""), 10);
        return aN == bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
    };
});

for (var orderIndex = 0; orderIndex < order.length; orderIndex++){
    var row = table.insertRow(orderIndex + 1);
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < tbl[orderIndex].length; colIndex++){
        var cell = row.insertCell(colIndex);
        var index = order[orderIndex][1];
        cell.innerHTML = tbl[index][colIndex];
    }
}
});
```

index

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
<?php 
include 'menu.php';
                    include 'shopJson.php';
                ?>
                <div id="lstEdit">edit</div>
                <div id="main"></div>
            </body>
        </html>
        <script>
            var lstActURL = "listings/active.json";
            var lstInactURL = "listings/inactive.json";
            var lstDraftURL = "listings/draft.json";
            var sectURL = "listings/sect.json";
            var lstAct = JSON.parse($.ajax({url: lstActURL, async: false}).responseText);
            var lstInact = JSON.parse($.ajax({url: lstInactURL, async: false}).responseText);
            var lstDraft = JSON.parse($.ajax({url: lstInactURL, async: false}).responseText);
            var sects = JSON.parse($.ajax({url: sectURL, async: false}).responseText);
            $("#mnLstAct").append("(" + lstAct.results.length + ")");
            $("#mnLstInact").append("(" + lstInact.results.length + ")");
            $("#mnLstDraft").append("(" + lstDraft.results.length + ")");
            document.getElementById("mnLstAct").style.fontWeight = "bold";
            $.getScript("listings.js"); 
        </script>
```

Comment: Please post the related HTML

Comment: Updating an attribute after a node is rendered in the DOM does not always mean that the related property is also updated

Comment: (side note) `.getElementsByClassName()` has performance implications because it returns a "live" node list. Using it and its `.length` property in each loop iteration is a huge drag on performance. Consider using `.querySelectorAll(".className")` and cache the `length` in a variable, then use that variable as the condition for the loop.

Comment: there is no html for this but a javascript, posted it

Comment: Where are `lstAct, lstInact, and lstDraft` declared?

Comment: added index to the buttom

Comment: should i provide a json file too?

Comment: @PaulS. how do i make sure related doms are updated

Comment: can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery `.attr()` method correlates to the actual attributes of a DOM element. However, from the JavaScript perspective, many elements have DOM properties that seem like they are the same as their HTML attribute counterparts, but are not because the property is updated in memory, while the attribute change updates the DOM. Sometimes, there are properties that don't even have an attribute counterpart (i.e. `selectedIndex` on `select` elements).

The point is that you have thess lines:

```
$("#"+lstId).attr("checked", true);

$("#"+lstId).attr("checked", false);
```

Where you are attempting to force an element to be checked, but that may not correlate to what you get when you check the `checked` property.

To account for this, use the `prop()` method instead of the `.attr()` method:

```
$("#"+lstId).prop("checked", true);
$("#"+lstId).prop("checked", false);
```

See the **[documentation for `.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** for details and a comparison between attributes and properties.

Comment: prop does not seam to affect the visual checking or unchecking of the checkbox

Comment: @AndreiPak As I asked in the comments, please post the HTML so we can really see what's going on.

Comment: just posted the javascript that replaces the html

Comment: @AndreiPak We need more. We need to be able to reproduce your issue. Where is `lstsToEdit` declared? Where is `tablesort.js`? When does `lstDisplay(type)` get called and what is passed to it? Additionally, there must be some HTML that serves as the skeleton for all this. We should see that too.

Comment: the html is pretty much <div id="main"> </main>